# what is the best/easiest to use encryption library in python

Tags: python, encryption, gnupg, pgp

I want to encrypt few files using python what is the best way
I can use gpg/pgp using any standard/famous python libraries?

Comment: Encryption is a tricky subject. Please add more information about what you're encrypting and why, and how your app needs to manage it. Specifically, you need to talk about how the secrets should be managed -- that'll determine whether you should use public key encryption or just a shared secret.

Comment: Basically i just want to encrypt some config files so that it is not readable buy other people but my program only.
i don't want any foolproof solution here becuase i will any way have to  decrypt files in my program
or can there be a fool proof way of doing this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[PyCrypto](http://www.pycrypto.org) seems to be the best one around.

Comment: It's comprehensive and the original author AMK is a respected Python developer.

Comment: Yes, but its current maintainer does not have any releases out (as checked today)

Comment: Pycrypto is quite incomplete. It lacks for example the padding schemes for asymmetric encryption schemes. Implementing them yourself is tricky and easily leads to insecure results. Much better is to use one of those libaries that are wrappers around well tested libs like openssl, pgp or gpg.

Comment: PyCrypto has all major RSA padding schemes starting from v2.5. In addition to that it does not require any external library, which is a plus I think.

Answer (score 7):

Try [KeyCzar](http://code.google.com/p/keyczar/)

Very easy to implement.

Answer (score 6):

I use [GPGme](http://www.gnupg.org/related_software/gpgme/index.en.html) The main strength of GPGme is that it read and writes files at the OpenPGP standard ([RFC 4880](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4880.txt)) which can be important if you want to interoperate with other PGP programs.

It has a [Python interface](http://pyme.sourceforge.net/). Warning: it is a low-level interface, not very Pythonic.

If you read French, [see examples](http://www.bortzmeyer.org/gpgme.html).

Here is one, to check a signature:

```
signed = core.Data(sys.stdin.read())
plain = core.Data()
context = core.Context()

context.op_verify(signed, None, plain)
result = context.op_verify_result()

sign = result.signatures
while sign:
    if sign.status != 0:
        print "BAD signature from:"
    else:
        print "Good signature from:"
    print "  uid:        ", context.get_key(sign.fpr, 0).uids.uid
    print "  timestamp:  ", sign.timestamp
    print "  fingerprint:", sign.fpr
    sign = sign.next
```

Answer (score 5):

I use [pyOpenSSL](http://www.egenix.com/products/python/pyOpenSSL/), its a python binding for [OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org/) which has been around for a long time and is very well tested.  I did some benchmarks for my application, which is very crypto intensive and it won hands down against pyCrypto.  YMMV.

Answer (score 4):

See Google's [Keyczar](http://code.google.com/p/keyczar/) project, which provides  a nice  set of interfaces to PyCrypto's functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I like pyDes (http://twhiteman.netfirms.com/des.html). It's not the quickest, but it's pure Python and works very well for small amounts of encrypted data.