# python+encryption: Encrypting session key using public key

Tags: python, encryption, public-key

I want to encrypt the session key using the public key. How does the PGP software do this?
Can somebody specify the procedure or function of encryption in Python?

Comment: Are you sure you need public-key (asymmetric) encryption? Except for cases when you need to publicly share session key between several sites/applications, symmetric (like AES or Serpent) encryption should be better.

Answer (score 3):

There's also the PyCrypto module that looks exactly like what you are looking for: http://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/ the API docs are here: http://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/apidoc/ and some nice docs with basic examples of encrypting/decrypting here: http://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/doc/.

I'll confess I haven't used this module, but it seems like you would establish a session with a public key, then use that to encrypt/decrypt the channel with a Crypto.PublicKey object. Then do the usual activity of generating a session key, communicating that over whatever channel you have. Finally, switch the channel to a Crypto.Cipher object using the session key.

Also, be sure to be very, very careful about how you obtain the value for your session key if security is a real concern, particularly on multiuser or only partially trusted machine.

Answer (score 1):

See [this post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=687173) for background information about the basic technology. That post is about encryption in general - for information about using gpg from Python, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1020320/how-to-do-pgp-in-python-generate-keys-encrypt-decrypt/1053752#1053752), for example.

Answer (score 0):

See [What is the best/easiest to use encryption library in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90413/what-is-the-best-easiest-to-use-encryption-library-in-python), which mentions a [PGP-compatible 
solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90413/what-is-the-best-easiest-to-use-encryption-library-in-python/90959#90959), [gpgme](http://www.gnupg.org/related_software/gpgme/index.en.html).

For reasons I ignore, nobody in [How to do PGP in Python (generate keys, encrypt/decrypt)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1020320/how-to-do-pgp-in-python-generate-keys-encrypt-decrypt/1053752) mentioned gpgme...